# Changing class variable, after inheriting, using the child class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Why is the second output not 2 2 2 and the third output not 3 3 3?
What is the reason behind such output?

```
class A(object): 
    val = 1

class B(A): 
    pass

class C(A): 
    pass

print (A.val, B.val, C.val) 
B.val = 2
print (A.val, B.val, C.val) 
A.val = 3
print (A.val, B.val, C.val)
```

Comment: `B.val = 2` creates a new class variable in `B` instead of changing the existing `A.val` while the reading access in the `print`s only searches for an existing variable (in the class itself, then the base class(es) and so on).

Comment: When you assign `B.val = 2`, you break the inheritance for that specific attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize all the classes using A() soo A.val, B.val, C.val all refer to the same value 1 (1 1 1)

When you modify B.val = 2 soo the value for B.val changes but the values for A.val and C.val remain the same (1 2 1)

Next you modify A.val = 3 soo A.val = 3 and since C.val is inheriting from A it also becomes 3. But B.val remains 2 since is has its own val attribute which is seperate from A.val (3 2 3)

Answer (score 0):

These are 3 classes with 3 separate class level namespaces. When a variable isn't found on a class, its parent is checked, then the next parent, all the way back to `object`.

In the second case, `A.val` is found directly. `A` doesn't know about the child classes that inherit and it would be weird if it did. Since both `B` and `C` inherit, which one would win? `B.val` is the expected 2. `C.val` doesn't find "val" in the C namespace, so looks to its parent, `A`.

Same with the third case. `A.val` is expected to be 3. "val" exists in the `B` namespace, so it's still 2. "val" doesn't exist in the `C` namespace, so its parent's value is used.